# confused with Mod rewrite RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

everything at my website is served from a master index.php at Document root

so normally all the functions looks like `./index.php?storage=seven`

i wanted to make it looks better, so tried to use Mod_Rewrite as shown below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/storage /index.php?storage=seven [L]
```

Now i am able to access the function using `./storage`

but when somebody types ./storage/  (an extra '/' at end)   or ./storage/some/junk  the Link still works  but the path to images/css/script in my page brakes(the paths to these is broken), which means, i just need it to be working for ./storage  and everything else should give 404  error (./storage/ and ./storage/*/*...  to give 40)

Please help me out here, i am very new to Mod_reWrite

Thanks

Comment: That rewrite rule doesn't match `http://example.com/storage` for example. The regex is wrong, so how do you *access the function*?

Comment: @faa   i changed my Rule, now it is        RewriteRule ^storage$ index.php?storage=seven [L]   and it works in all cases...
by the way in previous case 'seven' was hardcoded in the rule  and it was working.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small change in rule ... and it started working

```
    RewriteRule ^storage$ index.php?storage=seven [L]
```

By the way seven here is hard-coded from the Rule itself, please don't get confused with that

Thanks